# let grails generate without render template

Tags: grails, gsp

is it possible that the grails generate-all command is generating the create/edit.gsp views in a way that all fields are genereated seperatly and not just using

Like this:

```
<label for="myTicketNo">Ticket no.:</label>
<input type="text" id="myTicketNo" name="myTicketNo" value="${fieldValue(bean:myInstance,field:'myTicketNo')}"/>

<label for="description">Description:</label>
<textarea id="description" name="description" cols="180" rows="10">
${fieldValue(bean:myInstance,field:'description')}
</textarea>                            
<span class="button"><input class="save" type="submit" value="Create" /></span>
```

and not like:

```
<g:form url="[resource:userInstance, action:'save']" >
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <g:render template="form"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

It would make it easier for me to adjust fields seperatly and not writing that manually for each and every field I want the user to be able to change.
I'm on current grails .2.4.4.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use grails install-templates command so you will be able to modify edit.gsp to your liking.

```
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html
```

After modifying the installed tempĺates all generate code will follow its rules.

Comment: ok I got the template files but no idea how to modify them so they generate each field one by one. Any more info?